# How to configure SwiftShader device memory?

Tags: vulkan, swiftshader

I'm using SwiftShader for Vulkan rendering for a project where I can't rely on having a functioning hardware implementation. Today I encountered an ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY when trying to allocate a large chunk of device memory through `vkCreateBuffer()`. Since SwiftShader is a software implementation, I assumed that the device memory is configurable. Is it? If so, how is it configured?

Here is my call that fails:

```
size_t sz=1323371088; // > 1GB
size_t usage_flags = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT;
VkBufferCreateInfo bufferCreateInfo = vks::initializers::bufferCreateInfo(usageFlags, size);
bufferCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
int ret = vkCreateBuffer(device, &bufferCreateInfo, nullptr, buffer);
```

(This example is using the `VulkanInitializers.hpp` macros by Sasha Willems.)

Answer (score 2):

The maximum single memory allocation size for the Vulkan part of SwiftShader is defined in [VkConfig.hpp](https://github.com/google/swiftshader/blob/master/src/Vulkan/VkConfig.hpp#L91) and set to 1 GiB by default. If you need a larger limit for single allocations, increase the `MAX_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE`. Note that this can't be increased beyond 2 GiB (see comment in that file).

Comment: I just tried to increase the MAX_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE to 2GB, but the compilation then failed in `SpirvShaderImage.cpp` in the assertion `static_assert(OOB_OFFSET >= vk::MAX_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE, "the largest offset must be guaranteed to be out-of-bounds");`. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I checked the compilation and the assertion again, and found that could compile SwiftShader by reducing the memory by 32 bytes to: `constexpr VkDeviceSize MAX_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE = 0x80000000ull - 32;`. Why isn't this the default value for SwiftShader to begin with?